# Javascript hiding and showing dynamic content of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I hide and show the content of a div like this:

```
var header = null;
        var content = null;
        var mainHolder = null;
        var expandCollapseBtn = null;
        var heightValue = 0;

        header = document.getElementById("header");
        content = document.getElementById("content");
        mainHolder = document.getElementById("mainHolder");
        expandCollapseBtn = header.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

        heightValue = mainHolder.offsetHeight;

        header.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
        mainHolder.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',transitionEndHandler,false);

        function handleClick() {
            if(expandCollapseBtn.src.search('collapse') !=-1)
            {
                mainHolder.style.height = "26px";
                content.style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                mainHolder.style.height = heightValue + "px";
            }
        }

    function transitionEndHandler() {
        if(expandCollapseBtn.src.search('collapse') !=-1)
        {
            expandCollapseBtn.src = "expand1.png";
        }
        else{
            expandCollapseBtn.src = "collapse1.png";
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

This is fine if the content is static, but I'm trying to populate my div dynamically like so.

This is called from an iphone application and populates the div with a string.

```
var method;

            function myFunc(str)
            {
                method = str;
                alert(method);
                document.getElementById('method').innerHTML = method;
            }
```

I store the string globally in the variable method. The problem I am having is now when I try expand the div I have just collapsed there is nothing there. Is there some way that I could use the information stored in var to repopulate the div before expanding it again? I've tried inserting it like I do in the function but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

to replicate:

Here is the jsfiddle. jsfiddle.net/6a9B3 If you type in text between
 here

it will work fine. I'm not sure
 how I can call myfunc with a string only once in this jsfiddle, but if
 you can work out how to do that you will see it loads ok the first
 time, but when you collapse the section and attempt to re open it, it
 wont work.

If the only way to fix this is using jquery I dont mind going down that route.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use jQuery? I suggest taking a look at it. With it, it'd be as simple as `$("#div-id").show();` and `$("#div-id").hide();` to show and hide your div respectively.

Comment: Reason was this was working really nicely on an iphone before the content was dynamic. I dont really know much about javascript or jquery, could you show me how this would be done using jquery? What jquery libraries would I need to include?

Comment: From the code you have written here, I see nothing wrong. It doesn't look like it's clearing the content of the element with the id 'method', so it should stay the same. Can you give some more context?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: @dev6546 providing some html will make everybody's life easier, so we can see how your dom is laid out

Comment: You **never** _have_ to learn jQuery to solve a problem, it's a matter of how willing you are to spend the time learning to manipulate the DOM using native methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it working in other browsers?

can you  [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) for present functionality because it is hard to understand context of problem in such code-shoot...

there are tonns of suggestions :) but I have strong feeling that

```
 document.getElementById('method')
```

returns wrong element or this element not placed inside mainHolder

**update**: *after review sample in jsfiddle*

feeling about wrong element was correct :) change 'method' to 'info'

```
document.getElementById('method') -> document.getElementById('info')
```

Comment: If you type in text between here <p><span id = 'info'></span></p> it will work fine. I'm not sure how I can call myfunc with a string only once in this jsfiddle, but if you can work out how to do that you will see it loads ok the first time, but when you collapse the section and attempt to re open it, it wont work.

Comment: document.getElementById('method').innerHTML = method;

Comment: change it to document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = method; and everything would work fine...

Comment: Hi I've done what you said, here is the problem on video (small file) As you can see the text shows ok, but once you collapse it, it will not reopen again. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn37wj2houc22v8/test.mov

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Du95/ check this, I've made a bad-hardcoded-fix, this is ok as temp solution, but in production... no, no, no! whole expand logic is wrong... for example if you collapse and use myFunc for dynamic update - it will fail, lot of logical problems here, better to rewrite from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use document.getElementById('**content**') instead of document.getElementById('method') in myFunc.

Answer (score 0):

I really see nothing wrong with this code. However, a guess you could explore is altering the line 
`content.style.display = "none";`

It might be the case that whatever is displaying your html ( a webview or the browser itself) might be wiping the content of the elemtns, as the display is set to `none`